# Create ID number using Created by

Tags: calculated-column, id, whencreated

I am trying to create a unique ID for list items. The id number should have the format : year of creation & month of creation & id (1,2,3,etc) ;
the result i want to be something like 1711001 , 1711002, or 1712006, etc.

I created a column and put the formula :

```
= RIGHT(YEAR(Created),2)&MONTH(Created)&RIGHT(CONCATENATE("00",ID),3)
```

The first launch it work ok, but if i open and save again one item, its id number is going to "991200"

I am using only sharepoint in IE, no designer or programming tools.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal behavior, In your formula, the issue would be in the **ID field** that is not supported in the calculated column.

> Although the formula will accept the ID field without any error, The
>   ID value will not be calculated until the formula is updated again in
>   the calculated column field settings.

For more details check [The supported and unsupported columns in SharePoint calculated column formula](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/11/supported-fields-in-calculated-column-sharepoint/)

---

**The available workaround to use the ID in calculated column**

1. **Using Workflow**

   - Create a new ID field.
   - In the workflow, Set the new ID field value with the original ID column value - on item created or changed.
   - Now you can use the new ID field in the SharePoint calculated column Formula.
2. **Using Event Receiver**

   - In case you have a development background,  you can also use the Event Receiver to build your formula via code!

For more details check [Using id field in calculated column in Sharepoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/08/30/id-field-in-calaulated-column-sharepoint/)

Comment: Hi,   Thank you for reply, i read in other posts that ID column can't be used. But how i am making the workflow in internet explorer Sharepoint ?

Comment: You cant - but you can download SharePoint designer (Free tool) and make it there. If that's not an option for you, then you need to figure out another way without using the ID.

Comment: I have installed on my PC the Sharepoint designer, but when i want to open the site with it , i have the error saying: "this website has been configured to disallow editing with Sharepoint designer.  Contact your web site administartor for more information."

Comment: Check this bro, [This web site has been configured to disallow editing with SharePoint Designer](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/14/this-web-site-has-been-configured-to-disallow-editing-with-sharepoint-designer/)

Comment: Thanks, i gave up as I can't reach menus like showed there. I think i am under limited access, as it is sharepoint main site of corporate.